# EfCore ToListAsync() Throw exception with where condition

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have a problem with an async task that get items from the database with a specific condition
When i call the ToListAsync() i get this error

> Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Guid]' cannot be used for constructor parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Guid]'
>   Parameter name: arguments[0]

This is the code snippet:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Parent>> GetItems(List<Guid> TypeIds)
{
    var items = context.Parent.Include(x => x.Child).Where(x => new HashSet<Guid>(x.Child.Select(y => y.TypeId).Distinct()).SetEquals(new HashSet<Guid>(TypeIds)));
    return await items.Include(x=> x.Child).ToListAsync();
}
```

If I implement this method not `async` I won't get the error and all works.

Comment: You can't have a `Where` lambda like that for Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a `Where` lambda like that for Entity Framework, remember that the expression is going to get converted to SQL which has no idea what a `HashSet` is. You are probably looking for something like this instead:

```
var items = context.Parent
    .Include(x => x.Child)
    .Where(x => x.Child.Any(y => TypeIds.Contains(y.TypeId)));
```

Comment: Note that this is EF Core, so you could have any type of lambda. If it cannot be translated to SQL, it will be evaluated locally. How efficient is that is another story :) Anyway, if OP claim that non async version works and async doesn't, then it's simply yet another EFC bug.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ugh, I keep forgetting that EFC behaves like that, I hate it!

Comment: LOL, me too! From the beginning. But it allowed them to "release" EFC w/o fully implementing SQL translation for many constructs, `GroupBy` being the most famous.

Comment: @IvanStoev I do love .NET Core in general, but this has to be one of the worst (if not *the* worst) choices they made. And now we're stuck with it forever :/

Comment: @DavidG In my case the lambda you suggest won't work because I need the parent with exactly the Child of the kind passed in TypeIds and also in the Iqueryable I get i have the items I need. The problem is with the ToListAsync()